# Compiling C++ in cmd using MinGW on Windows 8

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmd, mingw32

I'm trying to compile c++ programs from the commandline, but I can't. I tried all the steps and instructions [listed here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/getting_started).

I got MinGW installed, but I get stuck in the last step of the installation that explains how to change environment paths. There simply isn't PATH part of it on the environment variables, and when I try to add it or even edit the one in System variables, compiling doesn't work (nothing comes up when I type g++ on the command prompt).

I've searched online for solutions, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Reinstalling MinGW32 resolved the issue of not being able to compile C++ at all.

Adding `;C:\mingw\bin` in the PATH variable under Advanced Settings in Properties in My Computer fixed compiling in cmd, as answered by @Chrono Kitsune.

Comment: Wait.  Nothing comes up when you type g++ at the command prompt?  No error message or anything else?

Comment: did you open a new command prompt after adding the PATH variable? Changes to the environment variables don't take effect until you start a new process?

Comment: consider installing [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org), it is actively maintained and installation creates a batch file that sets up the path for you.  Of course you could also install a unix-like shell such as MSYS2, that would help if you plan to build projects that come with makefiles or build scripts assuming such an environment

Comment: What comes up is this error: 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Additionally, I installed codelite and encountered the same error, something in mingw just won't work. 

The error in build output is
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C mingw32-make.exe -j 4 -e -f  Makefile
'mingw32-make.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
====0 errors, 0 warnings====

The return value I get for simple hello world programs is 0.

Comment: @PeterT I did still didn't work. Something was off, cause I actually had to create a PATH

Comment: @JerryJeremiah 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
:(

Comment: @M.M do I have to remove the existing mingw? (if yes how?) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @maltkat probably a good idea, there's no point having both

Comment: @M.M It says it recognizes it as a virus and won't run

Comment: @maltkat disable your antivirus

Comment: @M.M it still gives me the same mingw32 error even though i removed it and installed a new one, any suggestions?

Comment: did you install mingw-w64  , and if so, did you run the mingw-w64.bat file it came with? (and then type g++ in the same window you ran the batch file in)

Comment: @M.M It just comes as one .exe file

Comment: @maltkat sorry but I don't know what you are talking about

Comment: @M.M The mingw64 link you gave me just comes as a one .exe file, I ran it and I still get the same mistake when I type g++ in the cmd and the environments codelite and codeblocks still either can't run when i don't install mingw32 or run on mingw32 (codeblocks, I still didn't get codelite to run on them).

Comment: @maltkat on Windows, programs are usually packaged as one exe file, this is called an "installer" or "self-installer"  . You run the exe file and it "installs" the program which means that it (after downloading more data if necessary) copies the actual program files onto your system - of which there are hundreds or thousands of files  .   After running the mingw-w64 installer you will find a directory containing the file 'mingw-w64.bat', you need to open a command prompt and run that .bat file

Comment: I don't know why you mention codeblocks or codelite:  your question asked about using g++ on the commandline , which is nothing at all to do with codeblocks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either PATH variable is removed from regedit or it has grown to size of more than 2048.
To find out

1. Open cmd window and type PATH, if it prints the path.
   Something like:
   C:\Users\robin>PATH
   PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;............
   Then most probably it has grown to more than 2048 and that is why its not visible.
   You can update your Path variable in the command line by this command:
   set PATH=%PATH%;C:\cygwin64\bin
   So it will append Path with "C:\cygwin64\bin"
2. If that doesn't work. Then check in regedit  if these are present:
   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
   HKCU\Environment
   If not, export them from another PC and then import.

Comment: I tried, it says the system cannot find the file specified....

What do you mean by exporting them from another PC?

Comment: open regedit of another PC and export it. copy that file to ur current PC and import to regedit.

Comment: Editing the registry to fix this may require you to log off and log back on for the settings to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>Win+R</kbd> to open the Run dialog and type

   ```
   sysdm.cpl ,3
   ```
2. Click the "Environment Variables" button.
3. There are two sections: "User Variables" (top) and "System Variables" (bottom). You want to look at the top section.
4. If you don't have a `PATH` variable, click the "New" button and type `PATH` for the variable name. Otherwise, just double-click the existing `PATH` variable.
5. Now add the following to the end of the variable's value:

   ```
   ;C:\mingw\bin
   ```

   where `C:\mingw\bin` is the folder containing `g++.exe`.
6. Click OK on each dialog box to close it.
7. Open a new command prompt and try to execute

   ```
   g++.exe -xc -E nul
   ```

   If you still get an error, try logging off and logging back on.

Comment: I got to part 5 by going to Advanced Options on Properties of Computer, but when I added the line you suggested (not the one on the mingw site) it worked and I didn't get the error.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

well
the issue is wih your variable name....open the environment variable navigate to system variable save it as PATH not anything else
i.e
variabel  | value
PATH      | C:\mingw\bin

select ok and close re-run g++ in cmd it show fatal error...thats a sign its added

Answer (score -2):

I prefer using a Linux OS for compiling C/C++ programs. I use VirtualBox to host a Ubuntu machine and it works very well.

If you go that route to compile, navigate to the directory using the 'cd' command, and then type 'make' to compile and `./yourprogram` to execute.

Comment: Significantly more work is required to compile Windows programs using g++ in a Linux virtual machine (it is possible via cross-compilation, but non-trivial)