# How to compile a C programm using cmd?

Tags: c, cmd, path, dev-c++

I have installed Dev C++. Now I want to run my C code from Command window in windows 8.1 . I have added path of bin folder in dev c++ to environment variables. But still I am not able to compile my programm.
Any suggestion on how to compile it using cmd will be much appreciated.

Comment: Dev C++ is an IDE. not a compiler. Have you installed any c++ compiler? Install gcc first.

Comment: Install C/C++ compiler for example GCC. If you are on windows install MinGW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you've tried to do wouldn't work since Dev C++ is an integrated development environment and it has its own compiler (MinGW), besides, you only need a compiler so your best bet is to offer a look at this topic : [Compiling C++ in cmd using MinGW on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35833343/windows-8-compiling-c-in-cmd-using-mingw)
Side note : most basics are covered in almost every forum, so if you find yourself blocked don't hesitate to google it up or look for the question in this website itself

Comment: After adding Dev C++ path to PATH variables , it worked for me.
I am using command
gcc hello.c -o hello and hello.exe and it worked fine.